# Are there any developer tool out there that allows me to roll-out features incrementally and, at the same time, test them?

Tags: build, profiling, build-process

I have a huge project with a bunch of features. Each of these features are new to the product so I'm a bit worried how customers will perceive them. I'm wondering if there are tools out there that help me facilitate my features releases. Are there any analytic tools out there that let me measure which one is working and which isn't? I'm worried I might lose customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no such universal tool for testing everything in everyone. However there are some work flows and methodologies which helps to ensure released functionality quality. For example writing some tests in software level with some schedule should help a lot.
I cannot provide any concrete guidance since every team takes practices which suits best their needs.